# parse string into jsonarray in android

Tags: android, json

my array is

```
{"VideoItem":{"PlayUrl":"hello"}}
```

I want to access PlayUrl

Code I am using

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(retstring1);
JSONArray ja1 = obj1.getJSONArray("VideoItem");

for (int j = 0; j < aJson.length(); j++) {
JSONObject jsonO = aJson.getJSONObject(j);
JSONObject jo1 = (JSONObject)ja1.get(j);

String h=jsonO.getString("PlayUrl")

}
```

But its returning null.

Comment: `VideoItem` is an object. `<JSONObject>:{}` and `<JSONArray>:[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VideoItem` is not `JSONArray`, that is `JSONObject`. So you need to read it as `getJSONObject("VideoItem")`.

Use

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(retstring1);
JSONObject videoItem = obj1.getJSONObject("VideoItem");

String url = videoItem.getString("PlayUrl");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mistake:

You have made mistake by taking `getJSONArray()`.

### Correct:

Use `getJSONObject()` because your string/response contains only `JSONObject` (main and sub objects)

### Solution:

```
JSONObject mainObject= new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
JSONObject objVideo= mainObject.getJSONObject("VideoItem");
```